# equals() and == for the class object

Tags: java

I have enumeration emulation class. Both objects in main p and pp are passing `==` and `equals` test. Both tests are passed in case when

```
p = PacketType.None; 
pp = PacketType.None;
```

and both prints nothing in case

```
p = PacketType.StartOfOperation; 
pp = PacketType.None;
```

What actually are invoked in method `equals` and operator `==`? I think that `==` should not pas because it must look if those object have the same pointer. In other words it should look is it the same object (and in our case it is not).

```
public class PacketType {

    String Name = "9";

    public static final PacketType None = new PacketType("9");
    public static final PacketType StartOfOperation = new PacketType("1");

    PacketType(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PacketType p = PacketType.None;

        PacketType pp = PacketType.StartOfOperation;

        if (p == pp) {
            System.out.print("==");
        }

        if (p.equals(pp)) {
            System.out.print("equals");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please.. please read the naming conventions.

Comment: You don't have to use _"Enumeration emulation"_ classes, Java has [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Please use mixed case which starts with lower case for your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With objects `==` should be used to test whether they are references to the same instance of an object. `.equals(Object o)` should be used to check whether they have an equal value (however this behaviour must be implemented manually in custom objects, else it defaults to `==` behaviour).

A good example of this is with `String` people commonly make the mistake of using `==` over `.equals(Object o)` when trying to check if strings are equivalent.

```
String a = "my string";
String b = "my string";
String c = a;
//Each of these should then evaluate to true
a==c
b!=c
a.equals(b)
b.equals(c)
```

A full explanation of the `equals(Object o)` method can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), I can't find an equivalent for the equality operator `==` ([This one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) is vague and refers to primitives not Objects).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't `override` `equals`, in this case the default of `equals` will be `==`.

Answer (score 0):

They are a bit different.

`equals()` method is present in the `java.lang.Object` class and it is expected to check for the equivalence of the state of objects. That means, the contents of the objects. Whereas the `==` operator is expected to check the actual object instances are same or not.

Another difference is that the `equals()` method can be overridden. That way, you can change it to act like you desire.

Answer (score 0):

> == should not pas because it must look if those object have the same pointer.

Correct if two references point to the same memory object then == will pass.

```
equals()
```

will also pass if not overridden becuase default implementation of equals also check for memory objects equality using `==`. 
As a good practice we should override equals for custom classes to actually compare the attributes of the two objects. If all the attributes are equal then logically two objects are equal.

Answer (score 0):

It is fully expected that `None != StartOfOperation` and, since you have not overridden `equals`, your class inherits it from the `Object` class, whose implementation is

```
public boolean equals(Object o) { return this == o; }
```

As you can see, this is exactly the same check as just `==`.

Answer (score 0):

[If you see the docs of equls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

Answer (score 0):

== always use to check the reference equality but equals() use to check the value pointed by the reference.
Read String class to understand it in deep.(String Pool)